# Events gulp-nodemon are not firing

Tags: node.js, gulp

I am currently trying to write a gulp task that allows me to serve development code up through a node webserver and use browser sync to reload the page. In doing so i'm attempting to use the events with nodemon, so for example when start event occurs, I want my gulp to log what its starting. Currently the events for gulp nodemon are not firing at all. No error is being thrown and the web server is  starting. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
gulp.task('serve-dev', ['inject'], function(){
  var isDev = true;
  var nodeOptions = {
    script: config.nodeServer,
    delayTime: 1,
    env: {
      'PORT': port,
      'NODE_ENV': isDev ? 'dev': 'build'
    },
    watch: ['server.js']
  };
  $.nodemon(nodeOptions)
  .on('start', function(){
    log('*** nodemon started');
    // startBroswerSync();
  })
  .on('restart', function (ev){
    log('*** nodemon restarted');
    log('files changed on restart:\n' + ev);
  })
  .on('crash', function(){
    log('Server Crashed for some reason');
  })
  .on('exit', function(){
    log('Server Ended Cleanly');
  })
```

Here is my config File:

```
module.exports = function() {
  var client = './src/';
  var temp = './.tmp/';
  var server = './server.js';
  var config = {

    // Location of index.html
    index: client + 'index.html',
    // Temp folder
    temp: temp,
    // All of the js files to load
    js: [
      client + '**/*.module.js',
      client + '**/*.js',
      '!' + client + '**/*.spec.js'
    ],
    // Root Folder of App(Where to find index.html etc...)
    client: client,
    // Where to find build Sass and CSS files
    css: [temp + '*css', client + 'css/*.css'],
      // All Js to Vet
    alljs: [
      './src/**/*.js',
      './*js'
    ],
    // Path to Node Server
    server: server,
    //Sass to Compile
    sass: ['src/scss/*.scss'],

    // Bower and NPM Locations
    bower: {
      json: require('./bower.json'),
      directory: './bower_components/',
      ignorePath: '../..'
    },

    // Node Settings
    defaultPort: 7203,
    nodeServer: './server.js'

  };
  config.getWiredepDefaultOptions = function() {
    var options = {
      bowerJson: config.bower.json,
      directory: config.bower.directory,
      ignorePath: config.bower.ignorePath
    };
    return options;
  };
  return config;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Completely Unrelated answer, log method was not functioning properly, thus no log statements....sorry